# File transfer over WAN link causes corruption

Tags: powershell, networking, corruption, wan

I'm running into an issue with PDF files becoming corrupted on copy from one WAN location to the next.

I have a PowerShell script (code below) that runs nightly to copy a PDF file by Windows Task Scheduler, sometimes two, from a satellite office in Florida to our corporate network in Oregon.  These files are generally around 35 Megs, but have been seen as large as 65 Megs. The files are generated fine at the satellite location, but after the copy script runs at night, the file becomes corrupted and will not open.

Is there something I can do in the script to include some type of error correction to ensure the file doesn't corrupt?  Is there a better tool to use where I can ensure file transmission and maintain the integrity.

I'm not married to any solution just as long as I can automate the process and only copies the files generated that day.

Thank you for your help.
David

PowerShell Script

---

```
$SourcePath = "\\Satellite\packingslips"
$RemotePath = "\\Corp\Shared\Packing_Slips\Satellite"

$Curr_date = get-date
$Max_days = "-1"


Get-ChildItem $SourcePath |
    Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime.Date -ge ($Curr_date.addDays($Max_days)).Date) -and ($_.LastWriteTime.Date -le $Curr_date.Date)} |
    Copy-Item -Destination $RemotePath
```

---

*Don't laugh at my code.  It's not my strong point.*

Comment: Hi, you can try to replace `Copy-Item` with the native command `robocopy` (*robust file copy*). Syntax is not as clear but it performs very well.

Comment: If you run the script manually, does it work?

Comment: Another option besides sodawillow's robocopy suggestion would be to use BITS to copy the file via the `Start-BitsTransfer` cmdlet

Comment: That approximately shouldn't happen. Error correction might be able to re-copy until it works, but you shouldn't be getting regular, repeatable errors in 35MB of copying over TCP - that's hardly any data these days, and it sounds like failing hardware, a failing network link, or the file is still in use and being changed while you try to copy it.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick response.  I'll try both the "robocopy" and "Start-BitsTransfer" options and see where that gets me.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with TessellatingHeckler - I'd look at your error rates on your WAN interfaces...

However, I also agree that RoboCopy is a good way forward:

```
robocopy \\Satellite\packingslips \\Corp\Shared\Packing_Slips\Satellite *.pdf /minage:1 /log:<path_to_logfile>
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice and code example!  I'll give it a shot and see how it helps.